# passing parameter values inside/ outside classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 classes:

1. `schedule_GUI` in-charge of creating and populating default values (read from csv file).
2. `run_schedule` in-charge of switching on/off of physical switch in accordance to schedule.

`schedule_GUI` is master for `run_schedule` class to share csv file data (among other things), during `__init__`.

```
class run_schedule():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.sch_file = master.sch_file  #### sch.file is retrieved from master
        self.continue_task = master.continue_task
        self.tasks_total = master.tasks_total
        self.loop()
```

As you can see, in code below I can have multiple schedules in different tabs

now- A schedule can be updated using GUI and save csv file (part of `schedule_GUI`), BUT when it happens, it does not update `sch__file` in `run_schedule`.

Question: How can a master update its child?

```
init_parameters()

##Initialize GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("Advanced Schedualer")

note = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(note)#,height=40)
tab2 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(note)
note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One", compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.grid()

#Create GUI in TAB@
gui1 = schedule_GUI(tab1, num_switches)
gui2 = schedule_GUI(tab2, num_switches)

#Run Loop Shedules
loop1 = run_schedule(gui1)
loop2 = run_schedule(gui2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since the `run_schedule` class has a reference to a `schedule_GUI` instance stored in `self.master`, it could poll it for changes (I'm guessing in its `self.loop()`). Unfortunately there isn't enough code in your question to show you how to do this. Also, you really should read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) especially regarding the naming of variables and classes, as well as the recommended way to indent code.

Comment: Can you explain more on polling?

Comment: Polling is just the repeated checking of something. In this scenario the master class would need to have a method the child class instance could call periodically to see if `sch__file` needs to be updated. You can also arrange for `tkinter` to call a function after a certain amount of time has passed (and do that over-and-over to keep it repeating). That sort of thing can be setup using the universal widget method named [`after`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an example I wrote this code to demonstate passing values between different classes (inner and outer ) :

```
class A:
  class C:
    def __init__(self, master, v, i):
        self.x = v + i
        print("C variable was created")
        print("in C Class, and my master is:", master.firstname)
        self.CB = B(master) # create B Class var and passing A Class as Master

    def print_c(self):
        print("running function print_c inside Class C", self.x)

def __init__(self, first, last, birthday, *args):
    print("A class variable was created")
    self.firstname = first
    self.lastname = last
    self.bday = birthday
    #self.email()
    self.c1 = self.C(self, *args) #Create C Class variable

def email(self):
    def doit(arg1):
        print("this is value inside", arg1)

    print(self.firstname + '.' + self.lastname + '@' + 'gmail.com')
    doit(self.bday)
    print("this is value outside", self.bday)

class B:
def __init__(self, master):
    print("B Class created, inheret A Class parameters via a C Class:", master.firstname, master.lastname)



#running script :

a1 = A("Jhon", 'Doe', '13/12/1985', 11, 12) # create a1- an A Class variable with parameters
print("My email value from A Class:", a1.email()) # calling methon "email" belongs to a1
a1.c1.print_c() # calling c1 variable, part of a1 variable declared earlier
```